# CoreData Server Sort order on the client(iOS)

Tags: ios, core-data

I am developing an iOS app with Core Data. The app grabs data from the server and updates CoreData. The records in the database are updated/sort order on the server. What is the best solution to preserve the sort order on the client?

Is storing the sort order in another column the best solution? This data is going to be changing on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData (currently) does not preserve sort order.  If there's a natural sort ordering (i.e. by name, date, etc.) you do it on fetch, otherwise you'll need to add the ordering ("index") to your object model.

Note: this may not be the case in near the future. *hint, hint*